# I have a layer that when published looks fine except when viewed in Map Classic it has no color. I need to add the updated layer to an old map

Tags: symbology, arcgis-online

I have published a layer that when published looks fine except when viewed in Map Classic it has no color. I need to add the updated layer to an old map. How do I figure out what symbology is causing the issue.
[image: all symbology posts fine in Map Viewer]

[image: All symbols grey]

Answer (score 1):

Try republishing the web layer from ArcGIS Pro with the '**Use Symbol Types Compatible With All Clients**' setting turned on.

To do this, go to ArcGIS Pro's 'Share' tab and click 'Web Layer' -> 'Overwrite Web Layer'.  The 'Share As Web Layer' pane should then appear (possibly after a warning dialogue about pop-ups).

In this 'Share As Web Layer' pane, click on the 'Configuration' tab, and then click on the second sub-tab icon (hovering over it brings up the hint 'Configure Parameters').  The '**Use Symbol Types Compatible With All Clients**' setting is the last item on this view.

Note that you have to re-select this every time you want to overwrite the same published web layer.  It does not remember this setting either globally, nor on a per-layer basis, nor per-project.  (I keep having this problem every time I publish an update to an existing web layer and have to keep going back and re-publishing it again with this setting turned on, after finding the symbology all looking rather generic).

The help tip for this setting ('i' icon next to it) says that it publishes symbology that can be rendered by older clients.